# R futher selection of spllit list

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataset that has 31 columns and 10000+ rows:

I have already seperated the data based on 3 columns: Seanson, stage and Team so it seperates team in each seanson in each stage.

`sep_team_season_stage<-split(data,f=list(data$Season,data$Stage,data$Team), drop = TRUE)`

It returned a bunch of sublist that has 31 columns and I want the subset to only have 7 columns:

```
"Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS"
```

so i do:

```
sep_team_season_stage[c("Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS")]
```

it shows:

```
$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL
```

but when I call one of the sublist, it works:

```
sep_team_season_stage$`1999 - 2000.Regular_Season.BOS`[c("Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS")]
```

How to I get it work on every list?

Comment: If you only need 7 columns from all subsets, you can select those columns from larger dataframe before splitting it based on team, season and stage?

Comment: @KarthikS if I first selected "Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS" from the dataset then I have no seanson and stage input for split()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply` :

```
cols <- c("Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS")
lapply(sep_team_season_stage, `[`, cols)
```

However, I agree with Karthik, it is better to subset data first and then do the `split` so you can avoid this step.

```
sep_team_season_stage <- split(data[cols], 
                              list(data$Season,data$Stage,data$Team))
```

Comment: How can I do that? if I first selected "Team", "FGM", "X3PM", "FTM", "AST", "BLK", "PTS" from the dataset then I have no seanson and stage input for split()?